# how to convert this into a async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I want to be able to retrieve the users from the Firestore database and filter to find a match between the id of the current logged in user with the id of the user from the database. I am not able to do that because I can't figure out a way to change this to `async` function:

```
const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserData =  () => {
       onSnapshot(collection(db, "users"), (snapshot) => {
        let list = [];
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
          setData(list);
        });

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    }

    getUserData();


  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {

    const getLoggedUser = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        if (data) {
          const signedUser = data.filter((item) => item.id === uid);
          setLoggedUser(signedUser);
        } else {
          console.log("no matching data")
        }
      } else {
        console.log("no user found")

      }
    });

    getLoggedUser();
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to retrieve the users from the Firestore database and filter to find a match between the id of the current logged in user with the id of the user from the database.

You can use [`getDoc`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) instead that'll only fetch the user's document and will cost you only 1 read. Currently you are reading the whole collection that'll cost you N reads where N is number of documents in the `users` collection.

You can use `useEffect()` just once and query Firestore when the auth state has been updated. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore"

const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const uid = user.uid;
      console.log("User UID:", uid);
       
      const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid));
    
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        setLoggedUser(snapshot.data());
      } else {
        console.log("user document missing")
      }
    } else {
      console.log("User not logged in")
    }
  });
}, [])
```

Comment: I need to set data first to display all the users in the table